# Genson property read error

Tags: java, json, web-services, genson

I created a class from a json template with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and I use Genson to map my json with a Jersey based WS. 
This is the first lines of my "json class" :

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "public_key",
    "template",
    "signature",
    "due_date",
    "fulfillment_date",
    "template_lang_code",
    "clients_id",
    "electronic_invoice",
    "is_draft",
    "recurring_time",
    "comment",
    "currency",
    "items",
    "payment_method",
    "ts"
})
public class CreateInvoiceBean {
...
...
```

I have getters and setters also in my class too.

I have created a restfull Ws to handle post requests and i tried to send  jsons object with firefox RESTClinent plugin.

This is the first lines of my json object that i tried to send:

```
{
    "public_key": "7f566499549fc9e6d9cc69ca3b10d5f5",
    "template": "billingo",
    "signature": "9273882e8b3bc7f57e1ef3bc10041bc4bf9d835c152a1e0b810b77b3d51864ad",
    "due_date": "2015-10-30", 
...
...}
```

My WS Post handler method looks like this:

```
 @POST
 @Path("/invoice")
 @Consumes("application/json")
 @Produces("application/json")
 public String createInvoice(CreateInvoiceBean newBillingoInvoice) {

     LOG.info("invoicenum:. " +  newBillingoInvoice.getDueDate());

     return newBillingoInvoice.getDueDate();
 }
```

My request arrives, and the `createInvoice()` method invoked but if I call `newBillingoInvoice.getDueDate()` it's return null, but when I call `newBillingoInvoice.getSignature()` it's returning with the value that I sent in the request json.. And so on.. if I call `newBillingoInvoice.getXY();` returns `null` and if I call `newBillingoInvoice.getOtherSomething();` return with value.. etc..

My question is, how could it happen that one property is `null` and the other is not `null` in the same object? When I create the request I set all properties no one of them was `null`.

Please help me! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the name I think. In your json we can see that you use underscore insead of upper case at word boundaries. Like due_date instead of dueDate. And I suppose that the properties in your code follow the usual java naming convetion with upper case.

One solution would be to annotate with @JsonProperty those set and get methods to change the name from "dueDate" to "due_date".

BTW the generated code is not for Genson, JsonPropertyOrder isn't a Genson annotation.